# qbo3 Document Review Workflow

Tags: workflow, document, qbo3

I have a series of documents in a document imaging system that need to be manually reviewed.

I can query the relevant documents from my data warehouse via an API call (`Process/DataWarehouseDoucmentQuery`), which will return data along these lines:

| Account | Document | Status | IndexId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Document A | Late | 9876 |
| 12345 | Document B | Late | 5432 |
| 12345 | Document C | Late | 1098 |
| 23456 | Document A | Late | 7654 |
| 23456 | Document D | Late | 3210 |

The goal is to:

- Create a `Task` for each document
- Create a `Workflow` for each document
- Group the documents associated with the same account under common `Process`

Answer (score 0):

Configuration should include:

- Create a `Workflow Template`, perhaps named `Document Review`, that applies to `Attachment`

  - Add a `Task` to this workflow, perhaps named `Document Review`

You can use qbo's `ImportFile/BatchApply` feature to create a scheduled job along these lines:

Query: `Process/DataWarehouseDoucmentQuery`
Action:

```
Attachment/Save?
  Attachment={Document}
  &SubscriberID={IndexId}
  &Status={Status}
  &Decisions_DocumentReview_Decision={Document} Review
  &Process={Account}
```

More detail on the parameters you are passing:

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Attachment | This is the same as the name of your document; adjust as you see fit. |
| SubscriberID | This uses qbo's Subscription pattern to ensure you don't create duplicate documents. This assumes that your IndexId is effectively globally unique in your environment. |
| Status | Since it's part of your data warehouse query, might as well map it to `Attachment.Status`. |
| Decisions_DocumentReview_Decision | Any qbo object can save [related table data](https://github.com/quandis/qbo3-Documentation/wiki/api-overview#related-table-data) by specifying `{Child}_{Template}_*`. Note that when passing `Template`, you should remove any non-alpha-numeric characters from the template name. |
| Process | The `Attachment` module is based on qbo's `GenericObject`, which can be a 'child' of any other object. In this case, the `Attachment` will be bound to a parent `Process`, which will be created on the fly if required. |

---

Note that creating a parent `Process` record as detailed above required that the application setting for `GenericParentClasses` include `Process`. This can be verified from the Configuration > Modules > Matrix > Settings panel.

An alternative to adding `Process` to `GenericParentClasses` is to specify both an `Object` to indicate the parent, and {Object}_* to indicate parent field values:

```
Attachment/Save?
  Attachment={Document}
  &SubscriberID={IndexId}
  &Status={Status}
  &Decisions_DocumentReview_Decision={Document} Review
  &Object=Process
  &Process_Process={Account}
  &Process_OpenedReason=Just a Stack Overflow Example
```